# Why does my drawing lag after drawing for a long period of time?

Tags: ios, drawrect, cgcontext, cgpoint

I'm creating a drawing app. In the beginning my drawing is smooth. When I draw a bunch of circles for a long period of time, my drawing starts to get edgy. Perhaps it's the fact that an array can't handle too many points?

DV.swift:

```
   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent       event: UIEvent?) {
    lastPoint = touches.first!.locationInView(self)

    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    var newPoint = touches.first!.locationInView(self)

    lines.append(Line(start: lastPoint, end: newPoint))

    lastPoint = newPoint

    self.setNeedsDisplay()

}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    var veryFirstPoint = touches.first!.locationInView(self)
    lines.append(Line(start: lastPoint, end:veryFirstPoint))
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}


override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextBeginPath(context)

    for line in lines {

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context,line.start.x , line.start.y)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, line.end.x, line.end.y)


    }
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1)

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
    }
```

Example tested on my iPad mini 4:
On the left side is the jagged numbers after drawing a bunch of loops. the right side is the first few numbers I drew and they're smooth.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. You are having the CPU redraw many paths every time you add a new "line", that is after every touch. This becomes increasingly processor intensive the more lines you have. One solution is to only redraw the "dirty" parts of your view. You can do this by using `setNeedsDisplayInRect(rect:CGRect)` instead of `setNeedsDisplay()`. For example you can add the extension:

```
extension CGRect{
    static func rectWithTwoPoints(p1:CGPoint,p2:CGPoint) -> CGRect
    {
        return CGRectMake(min(p1.x, p2.x),min(p1.y, p2.y),fabs(p1.x - p2.x),fabs(p1.y - p2.y));
    }
}
```

This will give me a rect enclosing any two points. Now in your `touchesMoved:` and `touchesEnded:` we can call `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` like so:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let newPoint = touches.first!.locationInView(self)

        lines.append(Line(start: lastPoint, end: newPoint))

        lastPoint = newPoint

        self.setNeedsDisplayInRect(CGRectInset(CGRect.rectWithTwoPoints((lines.last?.start)!, p2: (lines.last?.end)!),-10.0,-10.0)) //would be better to not force unwrap and use magic numbers, but you get the idea
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let veryFirstPoint = touches.first!.locationInView(self)
        lines.append(Line(start: lastPoint, end:veryFirstPoint))
        self.setNeedsDisplayInRect(CGRectInset(CGRect.rectWithTwoPoints((lines.last?.start)!, p2: (lines.last?.end)!),-10.0,-10.0))
    }
```

Using `CGRectInset` to expand our rect a bit because we have a path width that if we only redraw the rect returned by rectWithTwoPoints would take into account.

Comment: This works! The only problem occurs when I draw for a certain time and as i begin drawing new shapes, it lags for a second (only when I start from a few points). Do you have any idea what this might be?

Comment: Update: I fixed the issue. All I did was copy and pasted self.setNeedsDisplayInRect in my touchesBegan and replaced the parameters the first two parameters with lastPoint. Thank you so much!